# Bundle File size trouble with webPack

Tags: npm, webpack, browserify

In my react app,on first time i was working with "browserify" for compile de es6 files to es5. But when i check the bundle file has a size for 1.3mb (so much) when my folder with all scripts have 200kb. I think, probably that *browserify* was including multiples times the same scripts. That is because I have (for example) "Config.js" and I include it on any file that I need
with

```
import Config from .'/config.js';
```

If i don't do that, the app shows errors saying that request that variable in that section. Then i change my manage from *browserify* to **webpack**. I road about this, because everything is new for me, and the docs say that *webpack read my dependencies and try to include once any file*. But **my bundle file keep sizing 1.3mb**.

This is my *dummy* webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './js/src/index.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules|libs/, //npm and bower_components(libs)

                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

This is my package.json, there you can see the browserify command that i was executing before try with webpack (The start command).

```
   {
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app description",
  "main": "js/dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "owl.carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-image-holder": "^2.0.1",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^0.14.0",
    "react-toastr": "^2.8.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "^13.3.0",
    "envify": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-uglifycss": "^1.0.6",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "uglify": "^0.1.5",
    "watchify": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch-js": "NODE_ENV=production watchify assets/js/main.js -t babelify -t bulkify -o dist/js/app.js -v --full-path=false",
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production && watchify js/src/index.js -v -t [babelify --presets [env] ] -o js/dist/index.js",
    "build": "browserify js/src/index.js -g [envify --NODE_ENV 'production'] -t [ babelify --presets [env] ]  -t  > js/dist/app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "app",
    "jidapp"
  ]
```

Comment: Is 200kb without the dependencies in `node_modules`?

Comment: Is 200kb the hole folder with my .jsx codes, without babel compilation. That is my app code. for this reason I don't understand why the compile code has that size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the devtool setting within your webpack.config.js.
Here is some info on what the different settings do. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
For production builds I typically use cheap-module-source-map. In development, I use eval.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './js/src/index.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
         test: /.jsx?$/,
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         exclude: /node_modules|libs/, 
         query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
         }
       }
      ]
    },
};
```

You can also look into other webpack optimization plugins here.  https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization

Comment: I put it. but the compile file keep sizing the same. I could check in the .map file that some files are including multiple times. (some files 12 times or some like that). Definetively this is the trouble, but i don't know how fix it. I tried including "new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()" But nothing happen

Comment: I don't know why sometimes I comment and later, i saw that my comment is not here. I maked the changes that you recommend to me, I could see on the .map file that some files appear multiple times. Can be that is repeating the code on the bundle file? I tried using *optimize.DedupePlugin()* but nothing happen.